# Android Card View in eclipse

Tags: android, android-cardview

I am trying to build sample application for Card View in the android eclipse setup. While doing this, I am facing the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.CardView`.

I have already added the cardview project with the `android.support.v7.widget.CardView.jar` as library within my sample project. Please help me resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support library is now separated into multiple projects so that you don't have to import everything every time ;) With Gradle this isn't such a big problem, but in Eclipse you have to manually import the libraries you need.

1. The project for the CardView is located in your Android SDK folder: Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\cardview
2. In Eclipse use "Import" and select "Existing Android Code Into Workspace" and import the CardView project
3. Go to Properties->Android of the new project, mark it as a library project and then Link it as a library project in your own project where the CardView can not be found

That should do it